# Using sed to add characters at the end of a line adds a new line

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, text-processing, sed

I am making a script to convert some Magic decklists from one format to another. I need to insert the set code for each card at the end of the line it is on. My code is:

```
sed -i "$line_number""s/$/""|""$set_code"/ "$deck_file"
```

Where `$line_number` is a line in the file, `$set_code` is text to be added and `$deck_file` is a file I am editing, all already defined in the code.

What I want that line to do is take:

```
1 Acidic Slime
```

and turn it into

```
1 Acidic Slime|M13
```

But instead it adds a new line and outputs

```
1 Acidic Slime
|M13
```

In the file. Any help is appreciated, I am sure I am just missing something in `sed`. I am open to using awk or any other command, it doesn't have to be `sed`.

Comment: your code seems to work for me. Are you sure your `$line_number` is correct?

Comment: Could you show the code where you set the values for `$line_number` and `$deck_file`? Btw, an easier variant to type out your current command with less confusing quotes would be `sed -i "${line_number}s/$/|$set_code/" "$deck_file"`.

Comment: Line number is set here:  
 number_of_lines="$(wc -l "$deck_file" | cut -d' ' -f 1)"
 line_number=3

 while [[ $line_number -lt $number_of_lines ]]; do
  ((line_number++))
  line=$(sed -n "$line_number"p "$deck_file")

It starts at 3 to skip a few lines of header and incriments immedietly to avoid going over the last line.  
deck file is here:
file_location="$(dirname "$1")"
deck_file="$file_location""/""$(basename "$1" .txt).dck"

Where $1 is a file to convert.  
I should mention I have set IFS=$'\n' at the beginning of the file because a lot of these files have spaces in them.

Comment: Im just realizing that the IFS may be the problem but i tried setting it to IFS=$' ' right before the sed and there was no change

Comment: @ByteCommander 

Through some experimenting I found out that there is a \r  at the end of each line that I was not aware of. Changing the $ in sed to \r fixed everything. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please don't post code as part of comments, it's can't be formatted and is barely readable. [Edit] your question to add it instead. Also, as you say you found a solution, it would be nice to post that as answer below so that future readers with the same problem can benefit. Thank you.

Comment: sorry, I am fairly new at stacksocial. I will keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was a `\r` character at the end of each line that I did not know about. This makes the cursor return to the beginning of the line. I noticed this by trying to echo `"$cardname""|""$set_code"` which output

```
|M13idic Slime
```

Comment: I did think of this and tested it. I got the result you show for your test, so I did not think it could have caused a newline